# WordPress files go missing daily at certain time ( malware? )

Tags: wordpress, malware

I'm using WordPress 3.8.1 and i've been building a custom theme form the last couple of months and four days from now the theme stylesheet went missing for no reason, that kept happening everyday and now is not only the style sheet, several files from the wp-inclues, wp-admin and plugins folder were deleted too.

I installed some security plugins (BruteProtecto, BPS Security and Better WP Security) and a malware scanner (Sucuri) but looks like that didn't stop that to happen again. Sucuri couldn't spot anything suspicious.

This happens only once a day and always at a certain time. (Around 7:00 am [UTC−06:00]). I've changed passwords for the admin account, the ftp and the cPanel but didn't help either.

Any thoughts? I'm pretty desperate.

Comment: Does WP itself allow you to set up some kind of cron/scheduled activities, that might include deleting certain kinds of files? If it does, maybe you thought you were doing something else and set it up to do this? That's all I can think of, if you've definitely ruled out external hackers. Of course, have you looked _every_ place that a hacker might have penetrated (inside WP or in other places in the server)? Maybe they placed a Trojan, cron job, or a backdoor on your site, in which case you need to go over every file and every setting with a fine-toothed comb.

Comment: Check with http://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar-cron/

Comment: Got the Debug-bar-cron plugin. It's listing some events witch some i recognize, some i don't.  

The ones that could match the execution time of the missing files i'm talking about are:

**wp_scheduled_auto_draft_delete** 
and
**wp_scheduled_delete**

The firts one is listed as a Custom Event, the second one as Core Event.

Do they sound familiar to you? I did a little research and they seem to be normal WP procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I had the problem quite same as you.
So I resolved that issue as below:-

1. first be sure about your theme if any unknown script presents or not.
2. upgrade wordpress.
3. change every login details like admin, FTP etc.
4. upgrade each Plugins from valid sources.some rough-scripted plugins may causes this type of issues because either they were downloaded from untrusted sites or not available in upgraded version.
   So list out all plugins, check them and upgrade it to compatible version of wordpress if not necessary to use than remove them.

Hope this will help you.
Because not sure which type you are facing through.